# How to send dynamic data in email in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I am trying to write a function that sends a notification email after a file has been uploaded.  My below code works if I hard-code the "send-to" email address.

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
        from_email = self.request.user.email
        send_mail('New Files have been Uploaded',
                  'New files have been uploaded.',
                  from_email,
                  ['sendto@email.com', ],
                  fail_silently=False)
```

I need to set the "sendto@email.com" dynamically based on the editor_email that is in the serializer.  Below is the serializer.

```
class VideoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    projectName = serializers.SerializerMethodField(allow_null=True)
    editor_email = serializers.EmailField(
        source='editor.email', required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Video
        # fields = '__all__'
        fields = [
            'url',
            'handle',
            'filename',
            'size',
            'source',
            'uploadId',
            'originalPath',
            'owner',
            'project',
            'uploadDate',
            'editor',
            'projectName',
            'editor_email'
        ]

    def get_projectName(self, obj):
        return obj.project.projectName
```

When I check the JSON response in the front end of the app, the value for "editor_email" is what I expect it to be.

I am relatively new to Django Rest Framework and there must be something I am missing here.  I have spent hours reading through the documentation and trying different things but nothing seems to work.

Please, can someone tell me how to set this email based on the serializer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the mail send code snippet from `views.py` and move it into `serilizers` as

```
# views.py
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
    from_email = self.request.user.email
    send_mail('New Files have been Uploaded',
              'New files have been uploaded.',
              from_email,
              ['sendto@email.com', ],
              fail_silently=False)


# serializers.py
class VideoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # your code


    def send_dynamic_mail(self, video_instance):
        from_email = video_instance.owner.email
        send_mail('New Files have been Uploaded',
                  'New files have been uploaded.',
                  from_email,
                  [video_instance.editor.email, ],
                  fail_silently=False)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        video_instance = super().create(validated_data)
        self.send_dynamic_mail(video_instance)
        return video_instance
```

Comment: The line `from_email = self.request.user.email` gives me an error saying "Instance of 'VideoSerializer' has no 'request' member".  I had to replace that with `video_instance.owner.email` and now everything works perfectly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you could get the field `editor_email` data in your function. If it only string data, then you could do it like this:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
        to_email = serializer.data['editor_email']

        if to_email:
            from_email = self.request.user.email
            send_mail('New Files have been Uploaded',
                      'New files have been uploaded.',
                      from_email,
                      [to_email, ],
                      fail_silently=False)
```

Comment: Yes, this also worked.  I wonder which is better practice... to put this type of function in the serializer or in the viewset?